# LongMonthNames usage in Delphi XE2 and Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe7

Why does `LongMonthNames[X]` alone (without name-space prefixing) not work in Delphi XE7, while it DOES work in Delphi XE2?

```
program LongMonthNames_Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
    // Works in both Delphi XE2 and Delphi XE7:
    Writeln(System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[12]);

    // Works only in Delphi XE2, does NOT work in Delphi XE7:
    // ("not work" obviously means does not compile because of errors in the source code)
    Writeln(LongMonthNames[12]);

    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: When you compiled your project in XE2, didn't you see a compiler warning about using TFormatsettings? Never ignore warnings, they exist for a reason...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In XE2, `LongMonthNames` was still its own global variable (which was `deprecated` in XE) in the `SysUtils` unit.  In XE3, that variable was removed. You have to use the `LongMonthNames` member of `TFormatSettings`, which has a global variable in the `SysUtils` unit:

```
var
  // Note: Using the global FormatSettings formatting variables is not thread-safe.
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
```

You don't have to write fully qualified path, just `FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[x]` will do:

```
Writeln(FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[12]);
```

If you create your own instance of `TFormattSettings`, it is safe to use in threads (as long as you obey usual thread safety rules):

```
var
  Fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin
  Fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
  Writeln(Fmt.LongMonthNames[12]);
end;
```

Comment: So would it be thread-safe if I create an instance of TFormatSettings in the respective thread?

Comment: @KenWhite: your link does not work. I think you are looking for this: [RTL Changes for XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE3#RTL_Changes_for_XE3) or this: [Deprecated Global Variables Removed; Use FormatSettings Instead](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Global_Variables)

Comment: @Remy: Yes, the first is what I attempted to link; I copied the URL directly from IE. Thanks.