# "LongMonthNames" variable not recognized?

Tags: delphi

I have this code in my unit:

```
unit clsDate_u;

interface
type
   TDate = class(TObject)
     private
          fDay, fMonth, fYear : integer;
     public
        constructor Create(sDate: string);
        function MonthName: string;
        function DaysPassedInYear: integer;
        function LongDate: string;
        function GetDay: integer;
        function GetMonth: integer;
        function GetYear: integer;
    end;
implementation

{ TDate }
uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils;

constructor TDate.Create(sDate: string);
begin
  fDay := StrToInt(copy(sDate,1,2));
  fMonth := StrToInt(copy(sDate,4,2));
  fYear := StrToInt(copy(sDate,7,2));
  if fYear <= 29 then
     fYear := fYear + 2000
  else
     fYear := fYear + 1900;
end;

function TDate.DaysPassedInYear: integer;
var
  iTotal, iCount: integer;
begin
  iTotal := 0;
  iCount := 1;
  while iCount < fMonth do
   begin
    iTotal := iTotal + DaysInAMonth(fYear, iCount);
    Inc(iCount);
   end;
  iTotal := iTotal + fDay;
  result := iTotal;
end;

function TDate.GetDay: integer;
begin
   result := fDay;
end;

function TDate.GetMonth: integer;
begin
   result := fMonth;
end;

function TDate.GetYear: integer;
begin
   result := fYear;
end;

function TDate.MonthName: string;
begin
   result := LongMonthNames[fMonth];
end;

function TDate.LongDate: string;
begin
   result := IntToStr(fDay) + ' ' + MonthName + ' ' + IntToStr(fYear);
end;

end.
```

I want to use the "LongMonthNames" variable in my function as you can see here:

```
function TDate.MonthName: string;
begin
   result := LongMonthNames[fMonth];
end;
```

Delphi says it is an undeclared identifier and sees it as an error, but I did in fact add SysUtils and DateUtils in my uses clause.

Why does it not recognize "LongMonthNames"?

I am working in a seperate unit, but I doubt that has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: When you wrote this code, you obviously read the documentation of the `LongMonthNames` thing. Just curious: didn't the documentation mention that it is a member of a `TFormatSettings` record?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Probably the code was written at a time where LongMonthNames [still was global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358545/longmonthnames-usage-in-delphi-xe2-and-delphi-xe7).

Comment: @UliGerhardt: Probably, yes, but when it failed to compile today, the first place to look would have been the docs! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `TDate` is a poor name since it collides with the standard Delphi [`TDate`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDate) type.

Second, the `LongMonthNames` thing you are looking for is a member of the [`TFormatSettings`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) record. Consequently, to access this member, you need an instance of such a record.

For instance, if you want localized month names, you can use [`TFormatSettings.Create`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Create) to create a format settings record for the current locale.

On the other hand, if you want non-localized (English) month names, you can use the [`TFormatSettings.Invariant`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Invariant) class function.

For example,

```pascal
var LMonthNames := TFormatSettings.Create.LongMonthNames;
for var LMonthName in LMonthNames do
  ShowMessage(LMonthName);
```

gives you localized month names while

```pascal
var LMonthNames := TFormatSettings.Invariant.LongMonthNames;
for var LMonthName in LMonthNames do
  ShowMessage(LMonthName);
```

gives you non-localized month names.

(Obviously, in real code you would not recreate the format settings record every time.)

Comment: Worth noting that, along with everything else in TFormatSettings, `LongMonthNames` used to be a naked global variable.  OP's confusion comes from reading, or having in their possession, legacy code from a time where this record did not exist.  There now exists a global `FormatSettings : TFormatSettings` record that now bundles all those previous globals into a single global record.  Naturally, avoiding that global record and doing things as you suggest is preferred, but when working with legacy code, as a stopgap, those old globals can all be prefixed with the new record to "make work".

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add "FormatSettings." before the "LongMonthNames", like this:

```
function TDate.MonthName: string;
begin
   result := FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[fMonth];
end;
```

Comment: Yes, that works thanks to the global variable `SysUtils.FormatSettings`. However, using global variables isn't ideal, and you could also equally well create your own global variable `MyFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create/Invariant`.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I see... Now it makes much more sense, this was an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for the help and explanation, it is greatly appreciated! :)